# Resolving open generic types in Unity with same type argument as parent

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an abstract generic class `LogWriter<T>`.  I have one implementation of it called `MultiClientLogWriter<T>` which wraps multiple `LogWriter<T>` instances and writes to all of them.  I'd like to make a MutliClientLogWriter wrapping a couple different kinds of writers the default.  I have this code but it does not work because (of course) you can't resolve open generic types:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof (LogWriter<>), typeof (TraceLogWriter<>), "trace", new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
  new InjectionConstructor(Severity.Debug));

unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof (LogWriter<>), typeof (LogSinkWriter<>), "sink",
  new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(Severity.Debug, logSink));

unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof (LogWriter<>), typeof (MultiClientLogWriter<>),
   new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
   new InjectionConstructor(unityContainer.Resolve(typeof (LogWriter<>), "sink"),
   unityContainer.Resolve(typeof (LogWriter<>), "trace")));
```

However, I want this to go down the chain (that is, if a `MultiClientLogWriter<Controller>` is requested I want a `LogSinkWriter<Controller>` and so on), so you'd think there would be some way to achieve this.

Comment: Just as an aside, why do your log writers need to be generic? What do they gain from it? Most logging libraries just use a `Type` parameter of the type they are performing logging for.

Comment: That's what I'm using it for... I guess those things are more or less equivalent but switching to nongeneric doesn't really solve my problem (I don't think?) because how will I resolve the type then?